# Not able to create Apps In Openshift free plan?

Tags: openshift, paas

I am not able to create any openshift apps .
I currently have only one app main-anandu.rhcloud.com which points to anandu.info  .

but when i create an app it says "i have reached gear limit of 0"?

I tried to ask on IRC but it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mostly because your application violated our [legal terms](https://www.openshift.com/legal). We understand that this isn't always intentional. So the best thing for your to do is first check your email inbox (the one that's associated with your account) for an email from us explaining why your application was removed. If you still have questions or can't find the email please feel free to email us at Openshift@redhat.com with your login ID and url of your app and I'll look into it.

Comment: i got the message. what can i do to get my account back. I really want it.